# How large would the electric field need to be to split the mj -/+1 626.6 nm line of neon?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy

I am an undergraduate considering an extension on a quantum beats experiment with neon. The premise is to excite neon atoms coherently from a metastable 'ground' state into a superposition of excited states (transistion wavelength 626.6 nm) which have been zeeman split by a magnetic field. The decay of the coherently excited states shows beats in a time domain analogue of Young's double slit experiment.

I would like to do essentially the same experiment but with the Stark effect instead of the Zeeman effect but I have been unable to find any literature which I can understand that would help me get a feeling for the electric fields involved. If i can get away with something below the kV range then I can probably do it.

Comment: I don't know the value of the electric field but surely you would find a Van de Graaff generator useful to create it. Sorry, couldn't resist. ;-)